# Regex: decimal positive numbers accepted, but not starting with point

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm quite new with regular expression, i'm using it in angularjs.
I need to check an input field, and I need to accept only positive decimal values with no more than 3 digits after the point:

```
3
3.5
3.567
0.236
```

and reject values like

```
0
0.
.
.6
.635
3.6589
```

I tried this regexp:

```
var result = /([1-9]\d*)\.(\d{1,3})/.test(value) || /[1-9]\d*(?=\s|$)/.test(value);
```

and more or less it works, but still

- it accepts values with more than 3 digits after the point, like `45.9876`
- it accepts `.356` values (a number starting with `.` )

what I'm missing?

Comment: Using ^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$ is a good idea, but my problem is that if you put 0, then you MUST put a decimal value, like 0.65, because 0 is not accepted. Moreover, .36 and 000.00 should not be accepted.

Comment: try this ^[1-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$

Comment: thanks @RakeshKumar, I already tried but this way it does not accepts values like 0.35 or 0.658

Comment: I guess that the correct answer is "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,3}$"

Comment: thanks!! this works =)